# Git push fails in Jenkins (works only when restricting to run on specific node)

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, push, xauth

I have a Jenkins job which does git push at the end.
There are 3 nodes - a master and 2 slaves.
The job completes successfully when the option to Restrict running the job on a specific node is set.
The job fails if that option is unset.
Error message is as follows:

`> git push git@GIT-SERVER:PROJECT/KBC.git refs/heads/master --tags # timeout=10
Failure in post build SCM action: Command "git push git@GIT-SERVER refs/heads/master --tags" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0`

I tried updating the ~/.ssh/config with the following entries however it didn't help and I got the same error.

> Host *
>         ForwardAgent yes 
>       ForwardX11 yes  
>   XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth

I also tried adding below entry but it failed with the bad config error:

> X11UseLocalhost no